# AS3 - Ruby encrypted communication?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionscript-3, encryption, as3crypto

I need a proven example to show how its possible to encrypt a string in AS3 and decrypt it in Ruby and vice versa ?, I found articles in PHP, but, I didn't find any in Ruby.

Can some one help by providing an example or some blog ?

Comment: Define "encrypt". Reversing the original string can also be  seen as an "encryption". Of course, it is totally insecure, but apparently it is possible to encrypt and decrypt in both languages. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What not just use SSL to encrypt the entire client-server conversation?

Comment: good idea, though, I think its costy, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create your own algorithm to encrypt your strings?

You can create a variation of [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), and use a similar code in both languages. So simple.

ROT 13 is something like this in AS3:

```
function calculate(src : String) : String {
    var charsMap : String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm";

    var calculated : String = new String("");
    for (var i : Number = 0; i < src.length ; i++) {
        var character : String = src.charAt(i);
        var pos : Number = charsMap.indexOf(character);
        if (pos > -1) character = charsMap.charAt(pos + 13);
        calculated += character;
    }
    return calculated;
}
```

What I recommend to you is make a variation, shuffling your string in some non-random pattern, and un-shuffle in your Ruby code.

Comment: I don't think ROT13 is secure enough, I am building a licensing solution for my software

Comment: I'm **sure** that ROT13 isn't secure(as any other popular kind of encoding/decoding, like Base64), that's why I wrote twice in my post to make a **variation** of that. I spoke of it just to start an idea about shuffling chars in a custom way.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, I appreciate you support